# Possibility of Star Wars style holograms

Tags: visible-light, hologram

We’ve all probably seen those neat little hologram projectors in franchises like Star Wars, are holograms on the level we see them in Star Wars possible? If so, what are some approaches to this type of technology and what are some practical applications?

Comment: *what are some practical applications?* I'm assuming you have seen Star Wars?

Comment: IIRC someone was doing images of telephones etc years ago, Woolf or Wolfe comes to mind.

Comment: In order for you to see a hologram, straight rays of light must come from the direction of wherever it appears to be, and enter your eye. In classic film-and-laser holography, those rays come from the film, and it seems as if the film was a window through which you can look to see the object. In Star Wars there is no obvious source of light either in front of, or behind, or at the location of the hologram. There is only the "projector" which is off to the side, not on the straight-line path between the hologram and the viewer's eye.

Comment: The Star Trek "Holodeck" concept is slightly more believable: There, we can assume that the entire walls, ceiling, and floor of the room are sources of light rays.